# How can you query an item in a list field in DynamoDB using Python?

Tags: python, list, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table that contains an item with the following attributes:

```
{
  "country": "USA",
  "names": [
    "josh",
    "freddy"
  ],
  "phoneNumber": "123",
  "userID": 0
}
```

I'm trying to query an item in a DynameDB by looking for a name using python. So I would write in my code that the item I need has `"freddy"` in the field `"names"`.

I saw many forums mentioning `"contains"` but none that show an example...

My current code is the following:

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('users_table')
data = table.query(
    FilterExpression: 'names = :name',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":name": "freddy"
    }
)
```

I obviously cannot use that because `"names"` is a list and not a string field.
How can I look for `"freddy"` in `names`?

Answer (score 3):

Since `names` field isn't part of the primary key, so you can't use `query`. The only way to look for an item by `names` is to use `scan`.

```
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('users_table')
data = table.scan(
    FilterExpression=Attr('names').contains('freddy')
)
```

Comment: I tried this and i’m now getting Attr is not defined...

Comment: [ERROR] NameError: name 'Attr' is not defined

Comment: `from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr`